# How to get yammer Likes count from embed

Tags: yammer

The documentation doesn't show how its possible to get the number of likes Yammer embed like you get with Facebook.

Is this possible in #yammer?

I'm using this embed script: https://developer.yammer.com/connect/#action-buttons

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple months so it could have changed, but the likes for the OG objects are not contained within the object but rather in the user's profile.  So you can't see the number of likes on an OG object.

To get this functionality, I ended up using the like/unlike API and on success, I update a database with the like count for the specific OG object.  Then on page load, I query the DB and get the like count.